# Why does the symbol of the Dirac operator have an "i" in it?

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-operators

Suppose we have a differential operator of order $n$ that maps sections of a bundle $E \rightarrow M$ to sections of a bundle $F \rightarrow M$:

$$ D(\sigma) = \sum_{I} \alpha_{I} \frac{\partial^{I}}{\partial x^{I}} +\ \text{lower order terms}$$

Where $I$ ranges over multi-indices of length $n$.

Then I read that the symbol is defined to be:

$$Symb(D)(\xi) = i^{n} \sum_{I} \alpha_{I} \xi^{I}$$

Where $\xi \in T^*_xM$. The symbol is supposed to be a map between the pullbacks of the bundles $E$ and $F$ over the bundle $T^*M$.

My question is: why is there a power of $i = \sqrt{-1}$ in the expression for the symbol? If the bundles are just real vector bundles, where would the $i$ come from?

(FYI I am reading this in Morgan's book on Seiberg Witten theory)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the $i$ in the differential operator makes it self-adjoint or essentially self-adjoint if we think it as a linear operator from hilbert space. So, this might be one of the reasons.

Comment: In the simplest case where the pseudo differential operator is defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, the symbol is the same as $F D F^{\dagger}$ where $F$ is the (standard) Fourier transform. So it's unitarily equivalent to $D$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "unitarily equivalent"? Does that mean I'm allowed to ignore the i?